# How to report a stack buffer overrun on Windows?

Tags: c++, exception

In the code shown below I have used all documented ways to detect an exception and produce a diagnostic.  It uses the C++ try/catch keywords, catches an SEH exception with the `__try/__catch` extension keywords, uses the Windows' AddVectoredExceptionHandler() and SetUnhandledExceptionFilter() winapi functions to install VEH/SEH filters.

Running this with Visual C++ 2003:
    /GS: outputs "hello,world!" and terminates with exit code 0.
    /GS-:  outputs "hello,world!" and terminates with exit code 0.

Running this with Visual C++ 2013:
    /GS: no output, terminates with exit code -1073740791
    /GS-: outputs "hello,world!" and terminates with exit with 0.

How do I produce a diagnostic in a VS2013 compiled program with /GS in effect?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>

#define CALL_FIRST 1  
#define CALL_LAST 0

LONG WINAPI MyVectoredHandler(struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS *ExceptionInfo)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(ExceptionInfo);

    printf("MyVectoredHandler\n");
    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
}

LONG WINAPI MyUnhandledExceptionFilter(_In_ struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS *ExceptionInfo)
{
    printf("SetUnhandledExceptionFilter\n");

    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
}

void f()
{
    __try
    {
        char p[20] = "hello,world!";
        p[24] = '!';
        printf("%s\n", p);
    }
    __except (EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)
    {
        printf("f() exception\n");
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    AddVectoredExceptionHandler(CALL_FIRST, MyVectoredHandler);
    SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(MyUnhandledExceptionFilter);

    try{
        f();
    }
    catch (...){
        printf("catched f exception\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code causes undefined behaviour. The only reliable way to "detect" is to check bounds before performing the out of bounds access

Comment: ... such as what would be done if you used a container type that does the detection. e.g. using the `std::string` for strings, and indexing it with the `at` member function.

Comment: Stack overruns are difficult to detect.  They only trigger when you overwrite the stack frame.  Try switching on runtime exception *Array bounds exceeded*.  It may work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The CRT function that handles stack buffer overruns detection, `__report_gsfailure()`, assumes that the stack frame corruption was induced by a malware attack.  Such malware traditionally messed with the fs:[0] SEH exception filters (stored on the stack frame) to get an exception handler to trigger the malware payload.  One of the ways to get data to turn into executable code.

So that CRT function cannot assume that throwing an exception is safe to do.  And no longer does in the CRT included with VS2013, goes back to ~VS2005. It will failfast if the OS supports it and, if not, ensures that a registered VEH/SEH exception handler cannot see the exception either.  Kaboom, crash to the desktop with no diagnostic unless you have a debugger attached.

The /SAFESEH option defeats this kind of malware attack so it isn't as serious as it once was.  If you are still at the stage where your code suffers from stack corruption bugs and your app is not popular enough to become the target of malware then replacing the CRT function is something you could consider.

Do talk this over with your supervisor, you never want to be personally responsible for this given the enormous liability to your client.  History rarely tells the tale of what happened to the one programmer whose code put an entire corporation out of business for a month.  But surely wasn't anything pretty.

Paste this code somewhere close to your main() function:

```
__declspec(noreturn) extern "C"
void __cdecl __report_gsfailure() {
    RaiseException(STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN, EXCEPTION_NONCONTINUABLE, 0, nullptr);
}
```

And plan to remove it again soon.

Comment: Link failed when add custom __report_gsfailure: error LNK2005: ___report_gsfailure 已经在 LIBCMT.lib(gs_report.obj) 中定义

Comment: Hmm, this is tested code, verified it worked on VS2015.  No idea what the Chinese text says, smells like gs_report.obj got already pulled in by another library so now there are two.  Use the linker's /VERBOSE option to find out why gs_report.obj was used.  And strongly, *strongly* favor building with /MD instead of /MT.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. According to my findings, msvcrtd also pulls in another __report_gsfailure so this works only in Release builds.

Answer (score 4):

There is no solution for the question as asked.

Overrunning an array causes undefined behaviour in standard C++, so no particular result is guaranteed.  Failure to give a reliable result is not a problem with the compiler - it is permitted behaviour.

I'm aware of no implementation that guarantees any specific behaviour in response to an overrun - VS certainly doesn't.   Which is hardly surprising as compilers are not required to do that (that is, essentially, the meaning of undefined behaviour).  The reason that is the case is that it is often difficult to reliably or consistently detect such occurrences.

This means the only consistent way to detect an array overrun is to check that array indices are valid BEFORE using them to access an array element and take appropriate actions (e.g. throw an exception which can be caught instead of doing the bad operation). The downside is that it does not provide a simple or reliable way to catch errors in arbitrary code - short of modifying all code to do the required checks.

Answer (score 1):

I would have liked to comment on the accepted answer, but I just joined and don't have enough reputation to do that yet.

I tried the solution with Visual Studio 2017 and had to make a couple of changes to get the solution to compile.

First I had to change the signature of __report_gsfailure to match one of Microsoft's header files to fix a compilation error.

```
__declspec(noreturn) extern "C" void __cdecl __report_gsfailure(_In_ uintptr_t _StackCookie)
{
    RaiseException(STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN, EXCEPTION_NONCONTINUABLE, 0, nullptr);
}
```

Next I encountered a LNK2005 error, which I was able to correct by adding /FORCE:MULTIPLE to the Linker->Command Line for my project's properties.